# How to query audit table to add start end dates

Tags: sql

I have an audit table that shows when a value was changed to a specific flag ('Y', 'N', 'A', 'B') and I want to organize the data so that for each ID it'll reflect when the start and end time was for that flag.

Sample data:

| ID | Flag_Audit | updateddatetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Changed Flag From: N To: B | 8/6/2021 2:58 |
| 1 | Changed Flag From: B To: Y | 8/6/2021 12:58 |
| 1 | Changed Flag From: Y To: N | 8/20/2021 10:58 |
| 2 | Changed Flag From: Y To: N | 8/1/2021 12:38 |
| 2 | Changed Flag From: B To: Y | 8/11/2021 10:58 |

Expected Output:

| ID | Flag | From Date | To Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | 8/6/2021 2:58 | 8/6/2021 12:58 |
| 1 | Y | 8/6/2021 12:58 | 8/20/2021 10:58 |
| 1 | N | 8/20/2021 10:58 | NULL |
| 2 | N | 8/1/2021 12:38 | 8/11/2021 10:58 |
| 2 | Y | 8/11/2021 10:58 |  |

Could you help me with this query?  Thank you!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
select id, right(flag_audit, 1) as flag,
       updateddatetime as from_date,
       lead(updateddatetime) over (partition by id order by updateddatetime) as to_date
from t;
```